# How can you see a list of edits a user has made in the past?

Tags: support, suggested-edits

Is there a way I can see a list of edits a specific user has suggested or committed in the past?

Really what I'm looking for is a list of edits made so I can see what is appropriate and accepted.  The FAQ and Help stuff sections are great, but I believe this would serve as a great learning tool.

Answer (score 3):

Go to a user profile, click on *activity*, and then on *suggestions*.

[image: screenshot]

That page shows all the suggested edits for that user. To know if a suggested edit was rejected, or accepted, click on the "suggested edit" link you see in that page for every suggested edit.

[image: screenshot]

That is the list of the suggested edits, which in my case is at https://drupal.stackexchange.com/users/199/kiamlaluno?tab=activity&sort=suggestions. For a list of other edits, see the page at *activity > revisions*; that page includes all the edits that were not suggested edits, such as edits to own posts, edits to Community Wiki posts (which are possible for who has a reputation higher than 100), and edits done when the user has the privilege of editing every post (which excludes editing tag-wiki posts, possible only to who has a reputation lower than 20K).

Comment: I knew that must have been tucked away somewhere.  Thank you for the details and the screenshots as well!